# Update bitbucket fork with latest code from main repo - but exclude removed files

Tags: git, fork, bitbucket

This is the setup:
I have a main repository

I have created a fork of this repository and have removed some unneeded files / directories that the fork will not need.

There has been some core updates to the main repository and I wish now to update my fork with these updates. But I just want it to update the files that the Fork still has.

How do I do this?

- I have tried to start a sync with the main repo but it shows all the files that were deleted in my new fork as incoming updates...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Read git documentation about branching and merging http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-What-a-Branch-Is

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with gitignore
http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

But you will have to ignore .gitignore itself. You just add ".gitignore" to it.

If it's already tracked by git, remove it from the cache:

`git rm --cached .gitignore`